# Появление изображений при открытии пользователем страницы

Tags: javascript

Нужно добавлять фото на страницу после того, как на нее зашел пользователь, добавление должно быть внутри блока с текстом.
Хочу найти что-то похожее на typed js, только для фото.

Сложность в том, что сначала появляется текст, который идет до изображения, потом появляется изображение, потом тот текст что после изображения, следующее изображение и так до конца текста.
Пример текста с изображениями:
"У Лукоморья дуб зеленый *, Златая цепь на дубе том *, и днем и ночью кот..."

**Важно:** библиотека, или подход который мне нужен должен быть **на чистом JS**.
Гуглила, не нашла ничего толкового.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/Politonius/d9ugkn8o/

```js
var arrPhoto = ["https://bpic.588ku.com/element_pic/02/36/05/19577a0f5765203.jpg","https://bpic.588ku.com/element_pic/16/11/07/fdebd0122c9317a1bc30be615ae2f1ac.jpg"],
textB = document.querySelector('.text'),
stringT = 'Эхочешь такого * или такого *',
smod=stringT[0];

var i = 1;                     
var n=0;
function myTest () {          
   setTimeout(function () {   
      smod=smod+stringT[i];
      if(stringT[i]=="*"){
      smod=textB.innerHTML+"<img src="+arrPhoto[n]+">";
      n++;
        }
     textB.innerHTML=smod;
      i++;                     
      if (i < stringT.length){
         myTest();
      }  
      
   }, 100)
}

myTest();
```

```css
img{width:50px;}
```

```html
<div class="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Плохо обрабатывать текст как html.